# How to remove items from list that have more then 20 characters?

Tags: python

I have a list, inside of list I have items. Some of items have more then 20 characters and I want to remove those items. But I don't want to remove items that have spaces. I provide minimal reproducible example...

This is a list...

```
some_list = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'black', 'verylongcharacterwords', 'very long character words']
```

I want to remove `'verylongcharacterwords'`, but I don't want to remove `'very long character words'`.

This is wanted output...

```
new_list = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'black', 'very long character words']
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name, it overwrites a built-in class name.

Comment: You say you're including a [mre], but you haven't -- it should include your attempted solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List comprehensions to the rescue:

```
>>> lst = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'black', 'verylongcharacterwords', 'very long character words']
>>> [l for l in lst if not any(len(w) > 20 for w in l.split())]
['one', 'two', 'three', 'black', 'very long character words']
>>>
```

Comment: He wants to test the length of the whole string, not words in the string.

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension with a condition.

```
new_list = [s for s in old_list if ' ' in s or len(s) <= 20]
```